# run rcp application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

There is a bunch of ways to run an application. I could run it from:

- plugin.xml overview tab
- from created product (file->New->Plugin development->Product configuration)
- manually create run configuration

The main difference which I want to know is between the first and the second option as it is the most confusing for me.

For the second the third option I think that by creating product configuration and running it first time new run configuration inheriting product configuration options is automatically created. After run configuration is created there is no more connections from product configuration and link configuration (at least I have not seen one)?

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1 - run via `plugin.xml` - is primary used when the plug-in in question uses the complete target platform. Unless you have set the target platform explicitly, this is the same as the IDE you are running. Of cause, you can then later restrict the used set of plug-ins for your launch configuration manually...
- Option 2 - run via product configuration - is used when you have defined a complete product. Every time you use this option, an underlying launch configuration is synched to match the product configuration. This is especially useful when you have defined you product in terms of features or only use a subset of the defined target platform. Also, this is useful when you wish to debug a product that is defined via a product configuration...
- Option 3 - run via manual created launch configuration - is an option I try to avoid as it often gets confusing when you change plug-ins, features or product configurations for the product... It *can* be very useful to maintain a launch configuration manually in the beginning of development of a new product/application as the initial (plug-in based) product configuration can be generated from a launch configuration.